# python: unicode problem

Tags: python, unicode

I am trying to decode a string I took from file:

```
file = open ("./Downloads/lamp-post.csv", 'r')
data = file.readlines()
data[0]
```

> '\xff\xfeK\x00e\x00y\x00w\x00o\x00r\x00d\x00\t\x00C\x00o\x00m\x00p\x00e\x00t\x00i\x00t\x00i\x00o\x00n\x00\t\x00G\x00l\x00o\x00b\x00a\x00l\x00
>   \x00M\x00o\x00n\x00t\x00h\x00l\x00y\x00
>   \x00S\x00e\x00a\x00r\x00c\x00h\x00e\x00s\x00\t\x00D\x00e\x00c\x00
>   \x002\x000\x001\x000\x00\t\x00N\x00o\x00v\x00
>   \x002\x000\x001\x000\x00\t\x00O\x00c\x00t\x00
>   \x002\x000\x001\x000\x00\t\x00S\x00e\x00p\x00
>   \x002\x000\x001\x000\x00\t\x00A\x00u\x00g\x00
>   \x002\x000\x001\x000\x00\t\x00J\x00u\x00l\x00
>   \x002\x000\x001\x000\x00\t\x00J\x00u\x00n\x00
>   \x002\x000\x001\x000\x00\t\x00M\x00a\x00y\x00
>   \x002\x000\x001\x000\x00\t\x00A\x00p\x00r\x00
>   \x002\x000\x001\x000\x00\t\x00M\x00a\x00r\x00
>   \x002\x000\x001\x000\x00\t\x00F\x00e\x00b\x00
>   \x002\x000\x001\x000\x00\t\x00J\x00a\x00n\x00
>   \x002\x000\x001\x000\x00\t\x00A\x00d\x00
>   \x00s\x00h\x00a\x00r\x00e\x00\t\x00S\x00e\x00a\x00r\x00c\x00h\x00
>   \x00s\x00h\x00a\x00r\x00e\x00\t\x00E\x00s\x00t\x00i\x00m\x00a\x00t\x00e\x00d\x00
>   \x00A\x00v\x00g\x00.\x00
>   \x00C\x00P\x00C\x00\t\x00E\x00x\x00t\x00r\x00a\x00c\x00t\x00e\x00d\x00
>   \x00F\x00r\x00o\x00m\x00
>   \x00W\x00e\x00b\x00
>   \x00P\x00a\x00g\x00e\x00\t\x00L\x00o\x00c\x00a\x00l\x00
>   \x00M\x00o\x00n\x00t\x00h\x00l\x00y\x00
>   \x00S\x00e\x00a\x00r\x00c\x00h\x00e\x00s\x00\n'

Adding ignore do not really help...:

> In [69]: data[2]
>   Out[69]: u'\u6700\u6100\u7200\u6400\u6500\u6e00\u2000\u6c00\u6100\u6d00\u7000\u2000\u7000\u6f00\u7300\u7400\u0900\u3000\u2e00\u3900\u3400\u0900\u3800\u3800\u3000\u0900\u2d00\u0900\u3300\u3200\u3000\u0900\u3300\u3900\u3000\u0900\u3300\u3900\u3000\u0900\u3400\u3800\u3000\u0900\u3500\u3900\u3000\u0900\u3500\u3900\u3000\u0900\u3700\u3200\u3000\u0900\u3700\u3200\u3000\u0900\u3300\u3900\u3000\u0900\u3300\u3200\u3000\u0900\u3200\u3600\u3000\u0900\u2d00\u0900\u2d00\u0900\ua300\u3200\u2e00\u3100\u3800\u0900\u2d00\u0900\u3400\u3800\u3000\u0a00'
>
> In [70]: data[2].decode("utf-8",
>   "replace")
>   --------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
>   Traceback (most recent call last)
>
> /Users/oleg/ in
>   ()
>
> /opt/local/lib/python2.5/encodings/utf_8.py
>   in decode(input, errors)
>        14 
>        15 def decode(input, errors='strict'):
>   ---> 16     return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors,
>   True)
>        17 
>        18 class IncrementalEncoder(codecs.IncrementalEncoder):
>
> :
>   'ascii' codec can't encode characters
>   in position 0-87: ordinal not in
>   range(128)
>
> In [71]:

Comment: My answer works without the error. But it depends wether you want to ignore or replace the undecodeable characters.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This looks like UTF-16 data.  So try

```
data[0].rstrip("\n").decode("utf-16")
```

Edit (for your update):  Try to decode the whole file at once, that is

```
data = open(...).read()
data.decode("utf-16")
```

The problem is that the line breaks in UTF-16 are "\n\x00", but using `readlines()` will split at the "\n", leaving the "\x00" character for the next line.

Comment: Strange, it fails for next line:

Answer (score 11):

This file is a UTF-16-LE encoded file, with an initial BOM.

```
import codecs

fp= codecs.open("a", "r", "utf-16")
lines= fp.readlines()
```

Comment: -1 balderdash. >>> raw = '\xff\xfeK\x00e\x00y\x00w\x00o\x00r\x00d\x00'
>>> raw.decode('utf_16le')
u'\ufeffKeyword'
>>> raw.decode('utf_16')
u'Keyword'
>>>

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT**

Since you posted 2.7 this is the 2.7 solution:

```
file = open("./Downloads/lamp-post.csv", "r")
data = [line.decode("utf-16", "replace") for line in file]
```

Ignoring undecodeable characters:

```
file = open("./Downloads/lamp-post.csv", "r")
data = [line.decode("utf-16", "ignore") for line in file]
```

Comment: In [21]: file = open ("./Downloads/lamp-post.csv", 'r')

In [22]: data = [line.decode() for line in file]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
<type 'exceptions.UnicodeDecodeError'>    Traceback (most recent call last)

/Users/oleg/<ipython console> in <module>()

<type 'exceptions.UnicodeDecodeError'>: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

In [23]: data = [line.decode() for line in file]

Comment: Ohh, do you want to ignore those invalid characters or replace them? Edited my answer assuming replacement.

Comment: In Python 3, files are opened in unicode mode by default. So they will not have a decode method.

Comment: I undid the downvote. But there's still a better way in Python 3: use the encoding argument for open. `open("Downloads/lamp-post.csv", encoding="utf-16")`.

Comment: Strange data do not seem to be changed... e.g. I see same array of utf-16 calling data

Comment: @Oleg: Are you sure it's 2.7? `/opt/local/lib/python2.5/` ?

Comment: see update on question... Auch it's 2.5: silver:~ oleg$ ipython
Python 2.5.1 (r251:54863, Feb 22 2008, 16:52:17) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.